# Image inside a framework not shown in iOS 7

Tags: ios, xcode6

I created a Cocoa Touch Framework which included a customized UIViewController with corresponding xib in Xcode 6. There is an image inside the xcassets in the framework. And it will be shown in the customized UIViewController. It works well in iOS 8 simulator. But when I run it in iOS 7 simulator (build the framework for iOS 7), the customized UIViewController is loaded and shown correctly. But the image inside is not shown? Any idea ? Thanks.

Inside my customized view controller:

```
-(instancetype)init {

    NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyViewController class]];
    if ( self = [super initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:bundle] ) {        
    }
    return self;
}
```

And my app which load the UIViewController from the framework:

```
MyViewController* vc = [MyViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: I don't think you can use cocoa touch frameworks on iOS7.

Comment: I thought I couldn't at first because it's an iOS 8 (Xcode 6) new feature. But I actually can run the framework built with iOS 7 in an iOS 7 simulator. But if I built the framework in iOS 8 then I can't run in an iOS 7 simulator.

Comment: I got this warning in iOS 7: "ld: warning: embedded dylibs/frameworks only run on iOS 8 or later". But it still runs. Maybe that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: yes I think it isn't loaded for iOS7. can you check if that framework is linked as optional?